# Where can I read the English translation of 诛心之罪 (Sin of Heart) novel/manhua?

Tags: resources

诛心之罪 (*Sin of Heart*) is a Chinese BL novel and manhua.

[image]

Where can I read the English translation?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Take note that this site doesn't condone piracy, so we will only mention legal/official sites if they exist. Answers/comments that mention questionable sites will be removed without prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The manhua can be found on [WebComics](https://www.webcomicsapp.com/) (the app) with the name [The Heart-Rending Crime](https://www.webcomicsapp.com/comic/5fe954b28c252b153e6701c4), but unfortunately, it costs money to read.